# Does a Chromecast device contain any private information?

Tags: privacy, chromecast

So I have a Google Chromecast that I'm gonna sell tomorrow because I don't use it enough. My question is: Do I need to do anything before selling it? Is there any personal data stored on it? Do I need to reset it so the other person won't know my WiFi or Netflix password?

Comment: Always reset any device that stores data when you're going to sell or give it to someone.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I believe the chromecast will store information from your router in order to connect. Either way, it's never a bad idea to reset electronics before selling them.

There are two ways to reset it:

1. Hold the button next to the micro usb port for 25 seconds, until the light starts flashing, then unplug usb
2. Go into the menu of the chromecast app and there should be a "factory reset chromecast" option

Comment: And if anyone's looking for a citation: https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3210071?hl=en under "How do I factory data reset (FDR) my device?"

Answer (score 15):

After you factory reset the Chromecast it is safe to sell.  On the settings menu for Chromecast there is a factory reset button.  Alternatively, there is a black button on the Chromecast.  Press it for 25 seconds while connected to the TV to factory reset.

Source:
http://www.tomsguide.com/us/factory-reset-google-chromecast,news-18294.html

Answer (score 2):

one advice is to make the factory reset,

AND check that the device no longer is able to auto login to any of the services that you have used the device for, just to be safe.

Comment: Chromecasts don't store any service authentication credentials.